# Child unable to react to gesture

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I have seen a video on the flutter Europe channel they explained how can we create our own widget , They taough how to build your own center i have created the same and its working fine but the issue is the widget below is no recognising any gesture.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class CustomPosition extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final Key key;
  final Widget child;

  CustomPosition({this.key, this.child});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    print("render created");
    return _RenderCustomPosition();
  }
}

class _RenderCustomPosition extends RenderBox
    with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
 
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child != null) {
      size = constraints.biggest;
      child.layout(constraints.loosen(), parentUsesSize: true);

      double dx = (constraints.maxWidth - child.size.width) / 2;
      double dy = (constraints.minHeight - child.size.height) / 2;

      BoxParentData childParentData = child.parentData;
      childParentData.offset = Offset(dx, dy);
    } else {
      size = Size(0, 0);
    }
    //super.performLayout();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      var parentData = child.parentData as BoxParentData;
      context.paintChild(child, offset + parentData.offset);
    }
    //super.paint(context, offset);
  }
}
```

If I use this custom position and provide a child to it, It will center it but the issue is if that child contains some sort of gesture recognition then it will not react to gestures. Please help me with what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the widget you created in another file like main.dart, just wrap it with GestureRecognizer() and set the on tap to whatever you want